# Polynomial time optimisation algorithm for a poly-time computable function with bounded number of maxima?

Tags: complexity-theory

Suppose we have a polynomial time algorithm for computing a function (we think of as existing on rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ of limited binary length n). We know that this function is made up of $m$ strictly monotone functions or equivalently that it has up to $m-1$ maxima/minima. Can we find these maxima in time that is polynomial in $m$ and $n$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  P.S. I'm not sure what you mean by "existing on rational numbers of limited binary length $n$"; you might like to try to state that more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider a function that is increasing, except in the small interval $[a,a+\varepsilon]$, where it decreases slowly.  Assume $\varepsilon>0$ is very small and the value $a$ is not known a priori.  Can you find the maxima in polynomial time?